# Formatting of text message sent from server

Tags: php, server, sms

Is it possible to format sms sent on user mobile from server ?
Like color of text, font of text etc.

I am trying to distinguish some text from other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, no.

This is due to SMS being an *unformattable* [format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_03.38#GSM_7_bit_default_alphabet_and_extension_table_of_3GPP_TS_23.038_.2F_GSM_03.38), meaning if you included, say HTML, the HTML tags would just be displayed as HTML tags, not formatted HTML.

Some newer phones allow for [Emojis, based on UTF-8 (mb4)](https://www.twilio.com/engineering/2012/11/08/adventures-in-unicode-sms), but even that's relatively limited in scope and your results [will vary](https://help.simpletexting.com/frequently-asked-questions/messaging/can-i-send-emojis-via-sms) depending on the recipient phone.

You can read more about the SMS format in this fantastically detailed memo: https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5724.txt